# iOS Xcode 4.3 Table View Controller & XML Parsing

Tags: ios, xcode4

I used a tutorial that I found previously mentioned on stackoverflow, however I am running into an issue when I try to incorporate the code into a Storyboard I've created.

My storyboard is setup as follows:

> Navigation Controller -> Table View Controller (static content) -> Table View Controller (where the XML should appear)

I get the following compiler error when I use the simulator and go to the Table View Controller where the XML should get output to:

> unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b5f300

From what I gather, the problem is with the Table View Controller that I have setup. I specify its class to point to the custom viewcontroller implementation files I've created, where all of the code is from the tutorial.

I've gone through every one of the tutorial files line by line to make sure I've used them properly in my own project and they all match. I have to believe the issue is a difference between the old-style of .xib files the tutorial uses and the new style of using the storyboard to layout the app. I even made sure the tutorial code compiles and works properly in my struggle to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Should I be creating a different type of view controller for the XML code to be displayed on versus using the drag-n-drop table view controller object the storyboard provides?

Answer (score 1):

> unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b5f300

This means that you're sending a message to an object that doesn't understand that message. You may have forgotten to implement some method that you're calling, or you may have an object of a different type than what you expect. Occasionally, it can also mean that you've got a bad pointer, i.e. there just happens to be a new object located at the same address that was previously used for some other object.

Take a look at the object at 0x6b5f300. What type of object is it? What message are you sending to it? Answering these questions should get you a lot closer to an answer.